# unable to redirect using nginx to another domain

Tags: redirect, nginx

Hey we changed the domain name from `domain1.ourapp.com` to `domain2.ourapp.com`

I would like to redirect requests to `domain1.ourapp.com` to `domain2.ourapp.com` using nginx conf. I want the browser url also to change.

In the nginx conf I have the following

```
server {
   listen         80;
   rewrite        ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
}
server {
  server_name domain1.ourapp.com;
  rewrite ^   $scheme://domain2.ourapp.com$request_uri permanent;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain2.ourapp.com
    # rest of the stuff
}
```

The trouble is that urls with `domain1.ourapp.com` return the right response but there is browser redirection happening. I would like some help in  this regard.

Comment: isn't the redirection what you want? what's the problem ?

Comment: The browser still says domain1.ourapp.com where as I want it to do a hard redirect to domain2.ourapp.com

Comment: do you access domain1 with http or https ?

Comment: any http gets redirected to https on my server. See the above config. Server is accessed through https only